# Getting Identity Column of new record in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Can anyone help? I have been using the entity framework and its going well :-)

But i have just added a new record using an entity class like so

this._entities.AddToUsers(user);

The AddTo is created automatically .. and users is my table... All great but how do i return the identity column?

The sounds like just what i need instead of calling a stored procedure, I did have a stored procedure before -

I suppose i can continue using the stored procedure but this means i have to convert my User entity class to Sql parameters.

I am using EFExtensions.

And once added do i need to call SaveChanges or something?

Any ideas ??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, AddToUsers only adds your object into the in-memory entity context - it isn't saved on disk just yet, and thus your new identity value hasn't been assigned yet.

Only calling .SaveChanges() will actually write the changes to the database - and then and only then, the identity value (if your field is of type INT IDENTITY) will get generated.

Marc

Comment: thank you.. yes that worked! Once i do SaveChanges i see the value is there

Comment: How did you get the ID back in code. For example Return this._entities.AddToUsers(user);?

Comment: @suggy1982: after the call to `.SaveChanges()`, your object's identity column is automagically populated - you don't need to do anything more - just read out the ID column